# Is there any pagination like code for saving JSON data to Realmdatabase

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a button and below it is the table view. Table view cell has some random data.On button click I am calling the the api(function name is : `api.urlRequest(userID: 80, businessUnitID: 2) )` .I have an API that has 35,0000 entries. What I want is to save that data in Realm database. The problem is that, when I am calling the save function, my UI freezes. I am appending the JSON data to Model and then saving it to database. I can get the start index and end index of the the JSON data.

What I tried was to call the API on background thread and when saving function is called, I am calling it on main thread. But this didn't worked.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,getAdhocJSONDelegate{
    let realm = try! Realm()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewRef: UITableView!
    var array = [NSDictionary]()
    var adhocData : [AdhocModel] = []//for appending the JSON data to the model
    var adhocDB : Results<AdhocDB>?// for accessing the database
    let api = AdhocAPIParamteres()
    var adhocJSONDatafromAPI : NSDictionary!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        adhocDB = realm.objects(AdhocDB.self)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("BUtton Tapped")
        api.urlRequest(userID: 80, businessUnitID: 2)
        api.delegate = self   
    }
    func appTutorialData(json: NSDictionary) {
        adhocJSONDatafromAPI = json
        let apiData = adhocJSONDatafromAPI.value(forKey: "data") as! [NSDictionary]
        print("Start Index of the data : ",apiData.startIndex)
        print("End Index of the data : ",apiData.endIndex)
        apiData.forEach { (abc) in
            let model = AdhocModel()
            model.site_id = abc.value(forKey: "site_id") as! Int
            model.atm_id = abc.value(forKey: "atm_id") as! String
            model.site_address = abc.value(forKey: "site_address") as! String
            adhocData.append(model)
            print("data appended")
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.saveToDb(data:model)
        }
    }
    
    func saveToDb(data: AdhocModel) {
        let adhoc = AdhocDB()
        try! realm.write {
            adhoc.SiteId = data.site_id
            adhoc.AtmId = data.atm_id
            adhoc.SiteAdress = data.site_address
            realm.add(adhoc)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to save data in such a way that my UI doesn't freeze.

Comment: There are quite a few issues - mainly you're not using a background thread to write your data so you're UI locks up. Also `var adhocDB : Results<AdhocDB>?` is a results object and then with `let adhoc = AdhocDB()` you're creating a results object over and over which is unnecessary. Just create the realm object like this `let myRealmObject = RealmObject()`, populate and write. See the documentation [Using Realm Across Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads) for a great example of how to write in the background.

Comment: @Jay I am new to iOS app development. I am not understanding the documentation properly. Can you please elaborate .

Comment: The question is still pretty vague and I don't know how your Realm objects are modeled but threw out an anwer - hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code and writing data to Realm on a background thread is covered in the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads) so I won't address that. Following that design pattern will correct the UI lockup.

This is another issue

```
func saveToDb(data: AdhocModel) {
        **let adhoc = AdhocDB()**
```

You want to write your populated model to realm, but AdhocDB is a Results object, not a Realm model object. Additionally the realm object created in `appTutorialData` which is *model*, is passed to saveToDb, then *another* object is created and then populated with data from the first object. There's no reason to do that (in this code)

Assuming AdHocModel is a Realm object, this is much cleaner

```
func appTutorialData(json: NSDictionary) {
    adhocJSONDatafromAPI = json
    let apiData = adhocJSONDatafromAPI.value(forKey: "data") as! [NSDictionary]
    print("Start Index of the data : ",apiData.startIndex)
    print("End Index of the data : ",apiData.endIndex)
    apiData.forEach { (abc) in
        let model = AdhocModel()
        model.site_id = abc.value(forKey: "site_id") as! Int
        model.atm_id = abc.value(forKey: "atm_id") as! String
        model.site_address = abc.value(forKey: "site_address") as! String
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(model)
        }
    }
}
```

You're going to want to wrap that write within a background thread (again, see the documentation) something like this

```
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    autoreleasepool {
        .
        .
        .
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(model)
        }
    }
}
```

You may ask about populating your array `adhocData.append(model)`. We don't know what you're doing with it but if you're using it as perhaps a dataSource for a table view or some other UI element, you may want to consider using a Results object instead of an Array.

A significant advantage is, if you have 35,000 objects, that's a pretty sizable array and if you have more, it could overwhelm the device as ALL of that data is stored in memory. However, Results objects are lazily loaded so you could have a much larger dataset without overwhelming the device.

Additionally, when Realm objects are stored in an array, they 'Disconnect' from Realm and loose Realm functionality - they will not auto-update nor will changes to the actual object in Realm be reflected in that array nor can you just update the object - it doesn't appear to have a primary key.

However, if you populate a Results object with those models, they will be live updating - so if for example the atm_id changes in Realm, that object will automatically be updated. If you need to change a property you can change it directly on that object within a write transaction.

So the pattern would be to have a class var of Results and load your objects into those results within viewDidLoad. As you add more models, the results object will automatically be updated.

To keep your UI fresh, you would want to add observers (aka [Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications))to those Results so you can be notified when an object is updated so you can reload your tableView for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I applied as per the above explanations and it worked like a magic.